# Does implicit instantiation a must in an instantiation?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <int N> int a = N;


template <typename T>
void func() { std::cout << a<0> << a<1>;}


int main() { func<void>(); }

template <> int a<0> = -1;
```

In the instantiation of `func<void>()`, symbols `a<0>` and `a<1>` are required.

In GCC implementation, the implicit instantiation of `a<0>` is after the specialization in the last line `template <> int a<0> = -1;` So it compiles and prints `-1`.

While in Clang, `a<0>` is instantiated within the instantiation of `func<void>()`. So it emits an error: explicit specialization of `a` after instantiation.

My question is

1. Which implementation is better?
2. Do the standard say anything about it? Is this unspecified behavior, undefined behavior, or implementation-defined behavior?

[Online compiler here!](https://godbolt.org/z/oz13rs)

Comment: `clang` is correct.  Even in gcc, the implicit instantiation is in the context of `func<void>()` in main().... it just chooses to defer actually processing that instantiation.

Comment: This is a No Diagnostic Required error, [see](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.expl.spec-7).